# Copy sheet using copyToEnd()

Tags: spreadsheet

I am trying out Keikai Spreadsheet. After importing an excel file, I wanted to copy a sheet using copyToEnd() but it deletes my original sheet. Am I doing it wrong?

```
Workbook srcBook = spreadsheet.imports("book1", new File(BOOK_FOLDER, "book1.xlsx"));
srcBook.getWorksheet().copyToEnd(spreadsheet.getWorkbook());
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently,`spreadsheet.import()` will change active Workbook to the just imported book; i.e. in this case `book1.xlsx`. So the original sheet is not deleted but just not active ( invisible).

Therefore, the `srcBook` actually equals to `spreadsheet.getWorkbook()` after importing. When you copy the `srcBook.getWorksheet()` to `spreadsheet.getWorkbook()`, you copy a sheet in the same book.  You will see 2 duplicate sheets in the active book.

The workaround is:

```java
final Workbook book = spreadsheet.getWorkbook();
Workbook srcBook = spreadsheet.imports("book1.xlsx", new File(BOOK_FOLDER, "book1.xlsx"));
srcBook.getWorksheet().copyToEnd(book);
spreadsheet.setActiveWorkbook(book.getName());
System.out.println("currentBook: spreadsheet.getWorkbook():" + spreadsheet.getWorkbook().getName());
```

In the future version, `spreadsheet.imports()` should not change active Workbook automatically unless it is the only workbook that bound to the application.